# Python Mongodb limiting by batch size times out

Tags: python, mongodb, collections, timeout, pymongo

I'm trying to scrape a huge (5gb) mongo database, so I'm limiting the batch size in order to be manageable. However, I'm still getting a time out error :/

My mongo knowledge is admittedly not the best, so if I'm doing something utterly stupid, please let me know! I already searched through the documentation and other questions and none of the answers have helped.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

collection = MongoClient(host="mongodb://xxx@xxx")
cursor = collection.all_companies.companies
batch = cursor.find().batch_size(1).limit(1) # I tried w/ other numbers too

for item in batch:
    print item
```

And here's what I'm getting:

> pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: xxx:xxx: timed out

Answer (score 1):

To get more than a single document as the result of a query we use the find() method. find() returns a Cursor instance, which allows us to iterate over all matching documents.

[About find()](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html#querying-for-more-than-one-document)

[About Cursor](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor)

```
connection = MongoClient(host="mongodb://xxx@xxx")
collection = connection.all_companies.companies
for item in collection.find():
    print item
```

Comment: I don't care about how many items I get, I just don't want the server to time out. It definitely times out when I don't limit the batch size